# Pivot DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data file in this format:

[image: datafile]

I want the columns to be grouped by month in a pivot table. When I pivot the data a column for each day is being created.

```
df = ex.read_excel("C:\\ExportReport.xlsx", "ExportReport")
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Forecast Qty', rows='Part', cols='Due Date', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

Is there a way to tell pandas to group the columns by month?

Comment: any reason not to use a pivot table within Excel?

Comment: A file like this is stored on my network every week with updated data. I want to create a cron job to run that will do a bunch of things with the data and create a new report. I currently have a macro in VBA that does everything but I can't easily run this on a schedule

Comment: thanks, I go back and forth between the two, and just trying to see how others view the benefits/drawbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to have a field that calculates the month. If this is going to span multiple years, will need to combine into one field.

```
df['YYYY-MM'] = df['Due Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

Then try yours, but change to the monthly field...

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Forecast Qty', rows='Part', cols='YYYY-MM', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```